# ginput and cross-hair in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am using a ginput function in Matlab to set the limit of a line with two points using ginput(2). A cross-hair appears, but it's not connected in the middle. Is there any way to change the appearance of the cursor?

As well, is it possible that a point will appear on the spot after I click on it?

I have read the answers here before, but nothing I need was here indeed.

Comment: Can you help us understand better what you desire? What do you mean "its not connected in the middle"? You dont like the graphical icon used?

Comment: I mean a fullcrosshair cursor, is there a way of customizing it?
As well,is it possible that a point will appear on the spot after I click on it?

Comment: Most likely not with standard MATLAB. Surely there must be a very obscure and undocumented way of hacking into the java engine running MATLAB graphs and changing it, but its not going to be easy. The second question is easier, I suggest you remove it from here and post it separately. Its better to have questions 1 by 1

Comment: Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 2):

Changing crosshairs in `ginput` cannot be done simply.

However, [here](https://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/156143-change-mouse-cursor-appearance-in-ginput) is a thread about the same thing, where the suggestion was to use a File Exhange function `MYGINPUT`. This allows the cursor to be specified, and achieves the same functionality as `ginput`.

http://uk.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/12770-myginput

As for a point appearing, this code:

```
figure(1)
[x,y] = ginput(1)
hold on
plot(x,y,'.')
hold off
```

should get you started!

I understand what you mean by "not connected in the middle":

[image: normal crosshairs]

But I'm not sure why you have an error?

```
[x,y] = myginput(1,'crosshair')
```

[image: New crosshairs]

The options for cursor type in `myginput` are:

```
'arrow', 'ibeam', 'crosshair', 'watch', 'topl', 'topr', 'botl', 'botr', 'circle', 
'cross', 'fleur', 'custom', 'left', 'top', 'right', 'bottom', 'hand'
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! 
Whenever I try myginput, I get an error in Command window: Error in newplot>ObserveFigureNextPlot

I can't post it as a separate problem, because due to my previous question, I am not allowed to give a different question within next 7 days.

Comment: Can you edit your question to add additional details for what inputs your are trying etc?

Comment: As a cursor pointer in ginput is fullcrosshair, but it's not what I need, because it's lines aren't connected (I know, its'not well explained).
That's the way I use it: ginput(2)   
I need to change the cursor pointer, If possible.
I am using it on an ECG signal to set boundaries between two points.

Comment: My code: QRS=myginput(2,'crosshair');
Two points are needed to be set, that's why 2. 
Still gives me the same error.

Comment: Any ideas of changing it, or why I am getting the error?

Comment: It should be `[QRSx, QRSy] = myginput(2, 'crosshair')`